# Save state of a webview

Tags: android, webview

I need to restore webview's state when the activity is destroyed. I was using `saveState` and `restoreState`, but it's not working anymore. It seems that they changed the behaviour of [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

> Please note that this method no longer stores the display data for this WebView. The previous behavior could potentially leak files if restoreState(Bundle) was never called.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: save webview state? what do you mean by that? You load webpages in webview or other static html pages from assets or file system. what is the meaning of **saving the state?**

Comment: Here's [a link](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2013/android/how-to-save-the-state-of-a-webview-inside-a-fragment-of-an-action-bar/?lang=en) this is what xactly what you want